# How to add a custom dropdown field for a product in VirtueMart?

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I am using joomla 3.x with VirtueMart.

I am trying to add a custom field "Country of Origin" to a product.
It would be the best that I can make use of the country list provided by VirtueMart.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to joomla. Instead of just minus my question, why don't you give me a little bit of suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
Components -> Virtuemart -> Products -> Custom Fields -> create new filed as new List option
```

Then select it in product details page custom fields section

Assume that you are using VM2.x

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks! I am using vm2.x. I can now add a custom field and make it a dropdown list. But is there any way I retrieve the default values from database?

Comment: Once saved on product details page it will load the default value correctly for that product in adminside right ?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and past this code in to your XML file in the following directory:

> administrator\components\com_helloworld\models\forms\helloworld.xml

```
<field 
    name="greeting"
    type="category"
    extension="com_helloworld"
    class="inputbox"
    default=""
    label="Day"
    description="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_FIELD_CATID_DESC"
>
    <option value="Plese select 'DAY'">--select days--</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</field>
```